# Syntax for including maxJsonLength in a standalone web.config for a Sharepoint Farm solution?

Tags: 2010, web-config, json

We encountered the following error in Javascript in a Sharepoint project:

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property.

Even though we've set `javascriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;` in the C#.NET code, it seems this setting:

```
<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000">
```

in the global web.config file (which is located at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config`) is being the bottleneck. **The error disappears when the `maxJsonLength` is set to a larger value like 10M this global web.config file.**

However, we'd ideally like this setting to be placed in a project-local web.config file, which we added in the `Layouts\<project-name>\` path, with the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="10000000"/>
    </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. No matter what the value for `maxJsonLength` in this file, the error still pops up.

My question is if the syntax in the project-local web.config is correct, or if we're missing any markup or xml attributes. Also, is there a different path for including this file other than in `Layouts\<project-name>\`? Why is the solution not picking up the setting from this file?